# Kali dnsspoof not redirecting

Tags: dns, kali-linux

I am trying to do some "dnsspoof" examples in kali/linux.I set up a windows machine(client:192.168.1.24) and a kali/linux (server:192.168.1.23)

1. I changed preferred dns address to server address in client.
2. I started `dnsspoof  -f /root/Desktop/hosts.txt host 192.168.1.24`

3.Using browser(Firefox) I am requesting a site that is in `hosts.txt` but I got `Server not found` error in browser

Also I am seeing all requested address in Kali

```
dnsspoof  -f /root/Desktop/hosts.txt host 192.168.1.24
dnsspoof: listening on eth0 [host 192.168.1.24]
192.168.1.24.53502 > 192.168.1.23.53:  25050+ A? www.test.com
192.168.1.24.62479 > 192.168.1.23.53:  47856+ A? www.test.com
```

`hosts.txt`:

```
173.194.35.64    *.test.*
```

Comment: waht DNS you put in windows machine???

Comment: @Hackaholic 192.168.1.23

Comment: your dnspoof is working fine but it does't has internet access, that y you got 404

Comment: @Hackaholic but if I request http://173.194.35.64/ from client browser it is working.

Comment: you testing in virtualbox or vmware???.

Comment: @Hackaholic yes one(kali) is in vmware other(windows) is in virtualbox but they are all in bridged network so I can ping from to other

Comment: just add this in your kali linux `arpspoof -i eth0 -t 192.168.1.44 -r 192.168.1.1`

Comment: @Hackaholic but I dont want to "arpspoof". I only need to dns spoofing.Do i need it?

Comment: yes you need arpspoof will spoof the arp then dnsspoof will work, give it a try